# jquery adding new class configuration on id?

Tags: jquery

`<area shape="poly" coords="63,10,64,38,89,37,91,10" class={"strokeColor:'0000ff',strokeWidth:5, fillColor:'ff0000',fillOpacity:0.6}" href="#" id="x1">`

There is a imagemap in my html and I want to dynamicly add a new configuration "alwaysOn:true" to the class attribute.

I cannot figure out how to add config option
How can I do that with jquery?

Comment: Where do you want to add that property? And why are you abusing the class variable to do it instead of using jQuery data?

Comment: I want to add that property to class={-here-,....}
I want to make an image map with highlighting and find some plugin and they describe it this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Look into jquery attributes](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

You need something along the lines of . . .

```
$("#x1").click(function(){

var oldClass = $(this).attr("class");
$(this).attr("class", oldClass + ' alwaysOn:true');

});
```

Comment: not only after click I want it immediately but dynamically so
is it $("x1").attr("class", oldClass + ' alwaysOn:true');